# Is there a benefit to implementing singletons in Neo?

Tags: neo4j

My business requirement says I need to add an arbitrary number of well-defined (AKA not dynamic, not unknown) attributes to certain types of nodes. I am pretty sure that while there could be 30 or 40 different attributes, a node will *probably* have no more than 4 or 5 of them. Of course there will be corner cases...

In this context, I am generically using 'attribute' as a tag wanted by the business, and not in the Neo4J sense.

I'll be expected to report on which nodes have which attributes.  For example, I might have to report on which nodes have the "detention", "suspension", or "double secret probation" attributes.

One way is to simply have an array of appropriate attributes on each entity. But each query would require a search of all nodes. Or, I could create explicit attributes on each node.  Now they could be indexed. I'm not seriously considering either of these approaches.

Another way is to implement each attribute as a singleton Neo node, and allow many (tens of thousands?) of other nodes to relate to these nodes.  This implementation would have 10,000 nodes but 40,000 relationships.

Finally, the attribute nodes could be created and used by specific entity nodes on an as-needed basis.  In this case, if 10,000 entities had an average of 4 attributes, I'd have a total of 50,000 nodes.

As I type this, I realize that in the 2nd case, I still have 40,000 relationships; the 'truth' of the situation did not change.

Is there a reason to avoid the 'singleton' implementation?  I could put timestamps on the relationships. But those wouldn't be indexed...

Answer (score 1):

For your simple use case, I'd suggest an approach you didn't list -- which is to use a node label for each "attribute".

Nodes can have multiple labels, and neo4j can quickly iterate through all the nodes with the same label -- making it very quick and easy to find all the nodes with a specific label.

For example:

```
MATCH (n:Detention)
RETURN n;
```